# Find the equation for the circle

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

Find an equation for the circle that has center 
$(−3, 4)$
 and passes through the point 
$(4, −2)$

I keep getting $(x+3)^2+(y-4)=113$

Comment: how did you get this?

Comment: you need to square the $y-4$. $113 = 49+64 = 7^2+8^2 \ne (4-(-3))^2+(-2-4)^2=7^2+6^2=85$.

Answer (score 3):

To find the radius of the circle that has center $(-3,4)$ and passes through the point $(4,-2)$, observe that the radius is the distance formula between two points:
$$r=\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2+(y_2-y_1)^2}=\sqrt{[(4)-(-3)]^2+[(-2)-(4)]^2}=\sqrt{85}.$$
So $r^2$ is actually $85$.

By the way, your $(y-4)$ needs the $2$ in its exponent. Your equation should be $$\boxed{(x+3)^2+(y-4)^2=85}$$

Answer (score 1):

The general equation for a circle centered at ($x_0$, $y_0$) with radius $r$ is given by
$$(x-x_0)^2+(y-y_0)^2=r^2$$
In your case you already have the center, then all you need to do is to substitute the point (4,-2) into the equation to obtain $r$.